# How to delete a folder in an azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

When running MapReduce jobs, the output folder should not exist otherwise the job fails. So when defining an azure data factory how can I define an activity to delete yhe existing output folder? Oozie has a preprocessing activity that can be used to delete the a folder but I don't kbow how to do it in data factory?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom activity prior to the MapReduce activity that will delete the folder using a programmatic approach by writing an executable and invoking it from the pipeline. Use this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/) as reference and examples . Basically you will need to upload the executable to a blob storage and Data Factory will execute it.